# Jenkins Master cannot find pom.xml file on Jenkins Slave Node during Maven build

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, master-slave

I have a setup whereby there exists a

**Jenkins Master** (jenkins-master) machine and a **Jenkins Slave Node**(jenkins-slave-one). The Slave Node is to compile Maven projects. The projects are pulled down from a Gitlab installation.

**When running the Jenkins job on the Master side, I get the following error in the console:**

> [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there
>   is no POM in this directory
>   (/var/jenkins/workspace/build-cc-restapi-dev). Please verify you
>   invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]

**Pulling the code from Gitlab works fine. It's just that the pom.xml is located here on the Slave Node/Machine:**

> /var/jenkins/workspace/build-cc-restapi-dev/ccinfieldworkserver/pom.xml

**Please Note**

```
The git cloning process is placing everything into:

=> /var/jenkins/workspace/build-cc-restapi-dev/ccinfieldworkserver
and not
=> /var/jenkins/workspace/build-cc-restapi-dev/
```

How can I fix this problem?

TIA

```
Started by user Jenkins Admin
Building remotely on ubuntu16.04-slave-one (build-maven-project) in workspace /var/jenkins/workspace/build-cc-restapi-dev
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git@mylocalserver:CCININ/fieldwork-server.git
 > /usr/bin/git init /var/jenkins/workspace/build-cc-restapi-dev/ccinfieldworkserver # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@mylocalserver:CCININ/fieldwork-server.git
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials Using jenkins ID on Gitlab to fetch code from GITLAB
 > /usr/bin/git fetch --tags --progress git@mylocalserver:CCININ/fieldwork-server.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > /usr/bin/git config remote.origin.url git@mylocalserver:CCININ/fieldwork-server.git # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git config remote.origin.url git@mylocalserver:CCININ/fieldwork-server.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@mylocalserver:CCININ/fieldwork-server.git
using GIT_SSH to set credentials Using jenkins ID on Gitlab to fetch code from GITLAB
 > /usr/bin/git fetch --tags --progress git@mylocalserver:CCININ/fieldwork-server.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/dev^{commit} # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/dev^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 039b646001804b5fba636e514e85c9093a95ef5d (refs/remotes/origin/dev)
Commit message: "second change to see what happens"
 > /usr/bin/git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git checkout -f 039b646001804b5fba636e514e85c9093a95ef5d
 > /usr/bin/git rev-list 039b646001804b5fba636e514e85c9093a95ef5d # timeout=10
[build-cc-restapi-dev] $ /opt/maven/bin/mvn clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.153 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-13T15:50:15+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/10M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/var/jenkins/workspace/build-cc-restapi-dev). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found that I could specify the location of the pom.xml file directly under the Build -> Invoke top-level Maven targets under the "Advanced" features.
TIA